# Why my friends' computer takes so long to move files?

Tags: hard-drive

What is happening? Is the hard disks damaged? How do I know?

Update: After a while it's running fast. It's as if some files are slow

Update: after I downloaded Crystal Disk Info, I got this

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: It might be a good idea to replace the picture with one that is not incriminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the S.M.A.R.T data for the hard drive.  There are lots of ways to do this, but one of the easier ones is to download Crystal Disk Info and run it.

S.M.A.R.T is logic built into most hard drives and SSD's which advise what the drives think of themselves.

It is likely that the disk is failing (and doing so quite badly).  Its a very good idea to ensure backups are all up-to-date.  There are other possibilities though - like other things (swap???) using the hard drive and slowing things down.  It is probable the disk is not working optimally due to fragmentation, but by itself the impact of fragmentation is nowhere near enough to describe this performance.

If you pull up task manager you should be able to look at DISK IO and see throughput.

Comment: Your smart values do not appear to show a dying disk.